# Recombining object after pickling-unpickling

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, persistent

I have a situation where one party (Alice) has a complex custom object, whose attributes are complicated and can involve circular references. Alice then sends this object to two separate parties, Bob and Claire, by pickling and sending through an (encrypted) socket. They each then modify one attribute of the object each, but what they change includes complex references to the object they received from Alice. Both Bob and Claire then pickle their own modified object themselves, and send it back to Alice.

The question is, how can Alice combine the changes made by both Bob and Claire? Because object persistence is lost on pickling/unpickling, the naive idea of copying the attribute that Bob or Claire created onto the original object doesn't work. I am aware of how persistent_id() and persistent_load() works in pickling, but I would very much like to avoid having to manually write rules for every single attribute in the object that Alice creates. Partly because its a big pile of nested and circularly referenced objects (some 10,000+ lines of them), and partly because I want flexibility to modify the rest of the code without have to change how I pickle/unpickle every time (and the difficulty of properly testing that).

Can this be done? Or do I have to swallow the bitter pill and deal with the pickling "manually"?

Here's a minimal concrete example. Obviously, the circular references could be easily removed here, or Bob and Claire could just send their value over to Alice, but not so in my real case.

```
import pickle


class Shared:
    pass


class Bob:
    pass


class Claire:
    pass


class Alice:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shared = Shared()
        self.bob = Bob()
        self.claire = Claire()

    def add_some_data(self, x, y):
        self.shared.bob = self.bob
        self.shared.claire = self.claire
        self.shared.x = x
        self.shared.y = y

    def bob_adds_data(self, extra):
        self.bob.value = self.shared.x + self.shared.y + extra

    def claire_adds_data(self, extra):
        self.claire.value = self.shared.x * self.shared.y * extra


# Done on Alice's side
original = Alice()
original.add_some_data(2, 3)
outgoing = pickle.dumps(original)


# Done on Bob's side
bobs_copy = pickle.loads(outgoing)
bobs_copy.bob_adds_data(4)
bobs_reply = pickle.dumps(bobs_copy)


# Done on Claires's side
claires_copy = pickle.loads(outgoing)
claires_copy.claire_adds_data(5)
claires_reply = pickle.dumps(claires_copy)


# Done on Alice's side
from_bob = pickle.loads(bobs_reply)
from_claire = pickle.loads(claires_reply)
original.bob = from_bob.bob
original.claire = from_claire.claire
# If the circularly references were maintained, these two lines would be equal
# instead, the attributes on the bottom line do not exist because the reference is broken
print(original.bob.value, original.claire.value)
print(original.shared.bob.value, original.shared.claire.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Partial Solution

I have a partial solution that works with some restrictions on the problem case.

#### Restrictions

The restriction is that Alice's object has only a single reference to Bob's and Claire's in a known place. Those latter two, however, can have arbitrarily complex references to themselves and to Alice, including circular, nested and recursive structures. The other requirement is that Bob doesn't have any reference to Claire and vice-versa: this is very natural if we require both of those objects to be updated independently and in any order.

In other words, Alice receives something from Bob which gets placed in a single tidy place. The difficulty is in making the references contained within Bob match up to the correct objects that Alice contains, but nothing else in Alice itself needs to be changed. This is the use case I need, and it isn't clear to me that the more general case is possible if Bob and Claire can make arbitrary changes to Alice.

#### Idea

This works by having a base class that creates a persistent id which does not change over the object's life time, is maintained by pickling/unpickling, and is unique. Any object whose references are to be maintained in this scenario must inherit from this class. When Bob sends his changes to Alice, he uses a dictionary of all the objects he received from Alice and their persistent id to pickle, such that those that all the references to pre-existing objects are encoded by the persistent id. On the other side, Alice does the same. She unpickles what Bob sent her using a dictionary of persistent id to object of everything she sent to Bob earlier. Thus, while Alice and Bob have different instances of everything, the persistent id of some objects are the same so they can be "swapped out" when pickling between different parties.

This can be made to work with existing code pretty easily. It just consists of adding a base class to all custom classes that we want to make persistent, and a small addition every time we pickle/unpickle.

#### Module

```
import io
import time
import pickle


class Persistent:

    def __init__(self):
        """Both unique and unchanging, even after modifying or pickling/unpickling object
        Potential problem if clocks are not in sync"""
        self.persistent_id = str(id(self)) + str(time.time())


def make_persistent_memo(obj):
    """Makes two dictionaries (one reverse of other) linking every instance of Persistent found
    in the attributes and collections of obj recursively, with the persistent id of that instant.
    Can cope with circular references and recursively nested objects"""

    def add_to_memo(item, id_to_obj, obj_to_id, checked):

        # Prevents checking the same object multiple times
        if id(item) in checked:
            return id_to_obj, obj_to_id, checked
        else:
            checked.add(id(item))

            if isinstance(item, Persistent):
                id_to_obj[item.persistent_id] = item
                obj_to_id[item] = item.persistent_id

        try:  # Try to add attributes of item to memo, recursively
            for sub_item in vars(item).values():
                add_to_memo(sub_item, id_to_obj, obj_to_id, checked)
        except TypeError:
            pass

        try:  # Try to add iterable elements of item to memo, recursively
            for sub_item in item:
                add_to_memo(sub_item, id_to_obj, obj_to_id, checked)
        except TypeError:
            pass

        return id_to_obj, obj_to_id, checked

    return add_to_memo(obj, {}, {}, set())[:2]


class PersistentPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    """ Normal pickler, but it takes a memo of the form {obj: persistent id}
    any object in that memo is pickled as its persistent id instead"""

    @staticmethod  # Because dumps is not defined for custom Picklers
    def dumps(obj_to_id_memo, obj):
        with io.BytesIO() as file:
            PersistentPickler(file, obj_to_id_memo).dump(obj)
            file.seek(0)
            return file.read()

    def __init__(self, file, obj_to_id_memo):
        super().__init__(file)
        self.obj_to_id_memo = obj_to_id_memo

    def persistent_id(self, obj):
        try:
            if obj in self.obj_to_id_memo and obj:
                return self.obj_to_id_memo[obj]
        except TypeError:  # If obj is unhashable
            pass
        return None


class PersistentUnPickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    """ Normal pickler, but it takes a memo of the form {persistent id: obj}
    used to undo the effects of PersistentPickler"""

    @staticmethod  # Because loads is not defined for custom Unpicklers
    def loads(id_to_obj_memo, pickled_data):
        with io.BytesIO(pickled_data) as file:
            obj = PersistentUnPickler(file, id_to_obj_memo).load()
        return obj

    def __init__(self, file, id_to_obj_memo):
        super().__init__(file)
        self.id_to_obj_memo = id_to_obj_memo

    def persistent_load(self, pid):
        if pid in self.id_to_obj_memo:
            return self.id_to_obj_memo[pid]
        else:
            super().persistent_load(pid)
```

#### Use Example

```
class Alice(Persistent):
    """ Must have a single attribute saved as bob or claire """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shared = Shared()
        self.bob = Bob()
        self.claire = Claire()

    def add_some_data(self, x, y):
        self.nested = [self]
        self.nested.append(self.nested)
        self.shared.x = x
        self.shared.y = y


class Bob(Persistent):
    """ Can have arbitrary reference to itself and to Alice but must not touch Claire """

    def make_changes(self, alice, extra):
        self.value = alice.shared.x + alice.shared.y + extra
        self.attribute = alice.shared
        self.collection = [alice.bob, alice.shared]
        self.collection.append(self.collection)
        self.new = Shared()


class Claire(Persistent):
    """ Can have arbitrary reference to itself and to Alice but must not touch Bob """

    def make_changes(self, alice, extra):
        self.value = alice.shared.x * alice.shared.y * extra
        self.attribute = alice
        self.collection = {"claire": alice.claire, "shared": alice.shared}
        self.collection["collection"] = self.collection


class Shared(Persistent):
    pass


# Done on Alice's side
alice = Alice()
alice.add_some_data(2, 3)
outgoing = pickle.dumps(alice)

# Done on Bob's side
bobs_copy = pickle.loads(outgoing)
# Create a memo of the persistent_id of the received objects that are *not* being modified
_, bob_pickling_memo = make_persistent_memo(bobs_copy)
bob_pickling_memo.pop(bobs_copy.bob)
# Make changes and send everything back to Alice
bobs_copy.bob.make_changes(bobs_copy, 4)
bobs_reply = PersistentPickler.dumps(bob_pickling_memo, bobs_copy.bob)


# Same on Claires's side
claires_copy = pickle.loads(outgoing)

_, claire_pickling_memo = make_persistent_memo(claires_copy)
claire_pickling_memo.pop(claires_copy.claire)

claires_copy.claire.make_changes(claires_copy, 5)
claires_reply = PersistentPickler.dumps(claire_pickling_memo, claires_copy.claire)


# Done on Alice's side
alice_unpickling_memo, _ = make_persistent_memo(alice)
alice.bob = PersistentUnPickler.loads(alice_unpickling_memo, bobs_reply)
alice.claire = PersistentUnPickler.loads(alice_unpickling_memo, claires_reply)

# Check that Alice has received changes from Bob and Claire
print(alice.bob.value == bobs_copy.bob.value == 9,
      alice.claire.value == claires_copy.claire.value == 30)
# Check that all references match up as expected
print("Alice:", alice is alice.nested[0] is alice.nested[1][0] is alice.claire.attribute)

print("Bob:", (alice.bob is alice.nested[0].bob is alice.bob.collection[0] is
               alice.bob.collection[2][0]))

print("Claire:", (alice.claire is alice.nested[0].claire is alice.claire.collection["claire"] is
                  alice.claire.collection["collection"]["claire"]))

print("Shared:", (alice.shared is alice.bob.attribute is alice.bob.collection[1] is
                  alice.bob.collection[2][1] is alice.claire.collection["shared"] is
                  alice.claire.collection["collection"]["shared"] is not alice.bob.new))
```

#### Output

```
C>python test.py
True True
Alice: True
Bob: True
Claire: True
Shared: True
```

All exactly as required

### Follow up

It feels like I'm reinventing the wheel here by doing my own nested introspection, can this be done better with existing tools?

My code feels rather inefficient, with a lot of introspection, can this be improved?

Can I be sure that add_to_memo() is not missing some references out?

The use of time.time() to create the persistent id feels rather clunky, is there a better alternative?